# Dojo Chart selective labels for x-axis & grid

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo, axis-labels

I need to create a dojo chart

http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8z/1

In the above link my chart has x-axis labels like

Current x-axis: **11:am, 12:40pm, 2:20pm & 4pm**

for the same labels i have grid lines.

Now the requirement is i just need 3 labels

Required x-axis: **10am, 1pm & 4pm**

chart shows data between 9:30 pm to 4 pm with 10 minutes interval.

here is working sample :- http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8z/1

here is code :- you need to run it on http

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>Code Bins</title>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dojo/dojo.js" ></script>


    </head>

    <body Body Params>
        <div id="chart1" style="width:300px;height:200px">
</div>    </body>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                    require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/ready", "dojox/charting/Chart",  "dojox/charting/action2d/PlotAction", "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Columns", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Grid"], function(declare, domStyle, ready, Chart, PlotAction, Default, Columns, Lines, Grid) {

    ready(function() {
        var chart = new Chart("chart1")
            .addAxis("y", { vertical: true, 
                fixLower: "major", 
                fixUpper: "major", 
                leftBottom: false,
                majorTicks:false,
                minorTicks:false,
                stroke: {color:"#FFF",width:0},
                majorTick:{length:0}})
            .addAxis("x", {
                labels: labels, /* Lables are coming from here*/
                majorTicks:false,
                majorTick:{length:4,color:"#FFFFFF"},
                majorLabels:true,
                majorTickStep:10,
                minorTicks:false,
                max:40,
                stroke: {color:"#CFCFCF",width:"1"}})
            .addSeries("y", close, {  fill: "#EBEBEB"})
            .addPlot("Grid", {
                    type: "Grid",
                    markers: true
                });

        chart.render();
    });
});

var close = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) { close.push(parseInt((Math.random() * 100) + 1200)); }
var labels = [{value: 1,text: "9:30am"},
{value: 2,text: "9:40am"},{value: 3,text: "9:50am"},{value: 4,text: "10am"},{value: 5,text: "10:10am"},{value: 6,text: "10:20am"},{value: 7,text: "10:30am"},{value: 8,text: "10:40am"},{value: 9,text: "10:50am"},{value: 10,text: "11am"},{value: 11,text: "11:10am"},{value: 12,text: "11:20am"},{value: 13,text: "11:30am"},{value: 14,text: "11:40am"},{value: 15,text: "11:50am"},{value: 16,text: "12pm"},{value: 17,text: "12:10pm"},{value: 18,text: "12:20pm"},{value: 19,text: "12:30pm"},{value: 20,text: "12:40pm"},{value: 21,text: "12:50pm"},{value: 22,text: "1pm"},{value: 23,text: "1:10pm"},{value: 24,text: "1:20pm"},{value: 25,text: "1:30pm"},{value: 26,text: "1:40pm"},{value: 27,text: "1:50pm"},{value: 28,text: "2pm"},{value: 29,text: "2:10pm"},{value: 30,text: "2:20pm"},{value: 31,text: "2:30pm"},{value: 32,text: "2:40pm"},{value: 33,text: "2:50pm"},{value: 34,text: "3pm"},{value: 35,text: "3:10pm"},{value: 36,text: "3:20pm"},{value: 37,text: "3:30pm"},{value: 38,text: "3:40pm"},{value: 39,text: "3:50pm"},{value: 40,text: "4pm"}];
// BOTTOM OF PAGE
                </script>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution  http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8z/2

extended axis2d and its some so simple. not there is not need to calculate steps on anything. just give whatever labels you want to give.

```
dojo.provide("myDojo.myAxis");
dojo.declare("myDojo.myAxis", dojox.charting.axis2d.Default, {
        calculate: function(min, max, span, labels){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this.ticks.major= [{ value:4, label:"10am"},{ value:22, label:"1pm"},{ value:40, label:"4pm"}]
            return this;
        }
    });
      dojox.charting.axis2d.myAxis = myDojo.myAxis;
```

Add type while adding axis

```
.addAxis("x", {
                labels: labels, /* Lables are coming from here*/
                majorTicks:false,
                majorTick:{length:4,color:"#FFFFFF"},
                majorLabels:true,
                majorTickStep:10,
                minorTicks:false,
                max:40,
                type:"myAxis",
                stroke: {color:"#CFCFCF",width:"1"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your X label sets a major tick step to 10 explicitly. Judging by your labels it should be 18: 1 is 10 minutes, 6 is 1 hour, 18 is 3 hours you want. So this part is easy. The problem is that steps are counted from 0, and 0 is 9:20am. You should start from a different number. One possible way to do it is to make 10am a zero. It means that you should shift your data and your labels back, like that:

```
var labels = [
  {value: -3,text: "9:30am"},
  {value: -2,text: "9:40am"},
  {value: -1,text: "9:50am"},
  {value:  0,text: "10am"},
  {value:  1,text: "10:10am"},
  {value:  2,text: "10:20am"}
  // and so on
];
```

Or start from 7am, like that:

```
var labels = [
  // we have no data for 7am, so we skip labels too
  {value: 15,text: "9:30am"},
  {value: 16,text: "9:40am"},
  {value: 17,text: "9:50am"},
  {value: 18,text: "10am"},
  {value: 19,text: "10:10am"},
  {value: 20,text: "10:20am"}
  // and so on
];
```

Try mapping your ordinals differently and you can achieve the desired effect.

PS: the same way you can control minor and micro ticks.

Comment: when i use negative values for axis it creates some black space on left side and y-axis still starts from 0.

Comment: Did you use negative values for your data too? It is not enough to change only label values.

Comment: hmm. not i didnt. I am not aware of how can i use negative values there?  Something like?  because it as already positive value. not sure about how to attache them with y-axis.. any way i found solution by overriding axis2d and so no need to worry about steps whatever labels i need i can setup there.